# How can I adjust the setting for OggVorbis encoding in Rhythmbox on Ubuntu Precise (12.04)?

Tags: rhythmbox, gstreamer, cd-ripping, sound-juicer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you edit the “Preferred Format” settings in Rhythmbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149153/how-do-you-edit-the-preferred-format-settings-in-rhythmbox)

I want to read a CD to my music library. I want to use OggVorbis for compression. I want to set the quality level to 6 (or 0.6). In previous versions I could manipulate the GStreamer pipeline manually:

```
audio/x-raw-float,rate=44100,channels=2 ! vorbisenc name=enc quality=0.6 ! oggmux
```

(I have seen that there is an easy to use slider for the quality in Ubuntu 12.10.)

How can I set the quality level for Ogg (and MP3) when "extracting a CD to library" on Ubuntu 12.04?

Thanks!

Cannot click on Settings in Rhythmbox and SoundJuicer on Ubuntu 12.04: 
[image]

Comment: I just found out that the settings for Ogg and MP3 encoding on Ubuntu Precise are already pretty decent. Actually, exactly how I would set them: quality level 6 for Ogg, and quality level 2 for MP3s. Both VBR, of course. This is consistent with the recommendation of Hydrogenaudio for both formats.

Answer (score 0):

**I found this on here** This might be the  answer for your question **[Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149153/how-do-you-edit-the-preferred-format-settings-in-rhythmbox)**